# Xamarin Test Recorder change JDK

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-test-cloud

I'm using Xamarin Test Recorder with Enterprise Subscription on Windows 10.

When trying to start a recording a test:
Editor (with loaded test class) -> Xamarin Test Recorder Icon -> Record new Test -> Select APK -> then selecting .apk file

In the blue status bar following error is given:

```
Failed connecting to app: Failed to execute: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\bin\keytool.exe -J-Duser.language=en -list -v -alias <alias> -keytore <pathtokeystore> -storepass <storepass> - exit code: 1 Error occured during initialization of VM Unable to use shared archive. An error has occurred while processing the shared archive file. Unable to unmape shared space.
```

I believe the error is routed in Xamarin Test Recorder executing the 32bit version of keytool.
I have tried running the same command in the windows shell.
When using the 32bit version of keytool the same error happens.
When using the 64bit version (same JDK version) no error is returned.

My question therefore is:
How can I change which JDK (or which keytool) the Xamarin Test Recorder uses?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem has been resolved by updating the JDK.